# Jump further down the page, in a separate component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Using Vue, I have a home page, that let's say consists of two components.

Introduction Component
List Component

I want to have a button in the Intro component, that jumps the user down the page to the List Component. Now, usually I would do something like -

```
<a href="#identifier">CLICK HERE...</a>

<div id="identifier">...TO JUMP HERE</div>
```

But, for some reason it is not working, and I believe it may be because I am technically jumping between two components, even though they are on the same page (the CLICK HERE... is on one, and the ...TO JUMP HERE   is on the other)

Am I correct in that being the issue? and if so, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can use to reproduce the problem and possibly help you better.

Comment: Is the component that holds the anchor(#) inside a v-if or v-show?

Comment: @SølveTornøe it is not, it is essentially the first div of the component.

Answer (score 2):

In the example below, this works as expected.

```js
Vue.component('intro', {
  template: `
    <section>
      <h2>Intro component!</h2>
      <a href="#list">Goto list anchor</a>
    </section>
  `
})

Vue.component('list', {
  template: `
    <section id="list">
      <h2>List component</h2>
      <h3>This is a long list:</h3>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="i in 500">list item {{i}}</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})

Vue.config.devtools = Vue.config.productionTip = false
```

```css
h2 {
  color: salmon;
  background-color: lavender;
  padding: 10px 0;

}
#list {
  margin-top: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<main id="app">
  <intro></intro>
  <list></list>
</main>
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the confirmation, I tried it as you have and, it does seem to work, but only when I click "<a href="#list">Goto list anchor</a>" twice.

First click adds it to my URL bar, second click moves the page... any ideas why that may be? :s

Comment: Are you using router?